Nielsen and Chuang Exercise 5.9

Let $U$ be a unitary transform with eigenvalues $±1$, which acts on a
state $|ψ〉$. Using the phase estimation procedure, construct a quantum
circuit to collapse $|ψ〉$ into one or the other of the two eigenspaces
of $U$, giving also a classical indicator as to which space the final
state is in.

I'm unable to properly understand what exactly the question is asking, does it mean to say $U$ has eigenvectors as $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$?
I tried an approach by assuming a general $|ψ〉$ and then applying the 1-bit phase estimation algorithm, but I'm unsure of what I did.

The question asks for a more general case rather than $U$ having eigenvectors $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$. $U$ is not specified nessesarily to be a single qubit operator.
Let $U$ be a unitary operator on $n$-qubits. Hence, $U$ is a $2^n \times 2^n$ matrix. This matrix has only two eigenvalues, $+1$ and $-1$.
Let there be $m$ degenerate eigenvectors $\{|u_1\rangle\,|u_2\rangle\, \cdots, |u_m\rangle\}$ corresponding to $+1$ eigenvalue.
Therefore, there will be $2^n - m$ degenerate eigenvectors $\{|u_{m+1}\rangle\,|u_{m+2}\rangle\, \cdots, |u_{2^n}\rangle\}$ corresponding to $-1$ eigenvalue.
Therefore, you can write down  $U$ in the spectral decomposition as
$$U = (+1)\sum_{i=1}^m |u_i\rangle\langle u_i| + (-1)\sum_{j=m+1}^{2^n} |u_j\rangle\langle u_j|\,.$$
Now you have some arbitrary $n$-qubit state $|\psi\rangle$. You can write this state in the eigenbasis of $U$.
$$|\psi\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{2^n}c_i|u_i\rangle\,.$$
Now, we can write it in two parts, one collecting all $+1$ eigenvectors and the other collecting all $-1$ eigenvectors.
$$|\psi\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{m}c_i|u_i\rangle + \sum_{j=m+1}^{2^n}c_j|u_j\rangle\,.$$
Now, we can normalize each part, where $a$ and $b$ are normalization factors.
$$|\psi\rangle = a\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{c_i}{a}|u_i\rangle}_{\text{say } |\phi_1\rangle} + b\underbrace{\sum_{j=m+1}^{2^n}\frac{c_j}{b}|u_j\rangle}_{\text{say } |\phi_2\rangle}\,.$$
Hence we can rewrite $|\psi\rangle$ as
$$|\psi\rangle = a|\phi_1\rangle + b|\phi_2\rangle\,,$$
where you can observe, $|\phi_1\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $U$ corresponding to $+1$ eigenvalue and $|\phi_2\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $U$ corresponding to $+1$ eigenvalue.
Now that you have this general $U$ and $|\psi\rangle$, you are asked to use Quantum Phase Estimation and estimate the phase. If you get observe phase $0$ (eigenvalue $+1$), $|\psi\rangle$ would collapse to $|\phi_1\rangle$, and if you observe phase $\pi$ (eigenvalue $-1$), then $|\psi\rangle$ would collapse to $|\phi_2\rangle$. As you suspected, single ancilla qubit is sufficient for this.

ok i think i understand it better , so what i did was just a special case of that?

@JasjyotGulati Yes, you did a very special case, where you assumed $U$ is a single qubit operation and $|0\rangle$ are $|1\rangle$ are its $+1$ and $-1$ eigenstates. So essentially, you forced $U$ to be Pauli-$Z$. Whereas the question asks for a completely general case.
